# VS2010 and NuGet, why v2.8? How to get 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Beforehand: This is not a 'cut and clear' programming problem. It is a toolchain problem and I do not know other places to ask it. If this is not an apropriate place to ask, excusses and I will redraw my question.

I want to use NuGet on my VS2010-pro installation.
When I go to Tools -> Extention manager... tab [online galery] I get the option to download and install NuGet, but only for version 2.8.2 (2.8.60318.667) while the latest NuGet package is 3.5.0

I want to be 'up to date' so why settle for 2.8.3?

First I looked around for any reason why for VS2010 only 2.8.3 is available but could find no answers.
Then I installed 2.8.3 with the idea to look for updates/upgrades through NuGet and get to 3.5.0 but had no success. Can't find a way to upgrade!

I cannot find a good reason why I should settle for 2.8.3 and I cannot find a way to upgrade for the VS2010 tool version of NuGet.
But I can install the CLI version of 3.5.0 without any problems.

What is the reason that for VS2010 NuGet is limited to 2.8.0, is that the case anyway or do I mis something here?

If I install NuGet CLI 3.5.0 what problems will I get with VS2010 and the 2.8.3 version?

I looked around, read a lot about NuGet but can't find an answer to these questions.
Does anybody have an idea or who can point me to a location where I can find an answer?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet 2.8.3 is the latest version that supports VS2010. So you won't be able to use 3.5.0 from VS2010. Looks like 3.5.0 CLI is your best bet.

Comment: any reason why?

Comment: I think supporting older versions of VS just meant more work for NuGet developers. It's common that old versions of soft loses support by newer tools